# Use sed in groovy to replace a value in json file

Tags: groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I have a json file with the below content:

```
"containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "image": "***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xyz"
  }
]
```

Now i want to replace the url for image with a new value. So in my jenkins scripted groovy file, i store this existing url value under some variable and then enter the new url value appended by build number. So i try to do the following:

```
newimageurl="\"***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xyz:v_$BUILD_NUMBER\""
oldimageurl="\"***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xyz\""
sed -i -e 's#'"$oldimageurl"'#'"$newimageurl"'#' ./myfile.json
```

But it ends with error both for syntax for newimageurl for the `v_$BUILD_NUMBER` and then for sed command.

How to resolve this?

Comment: You probably need to escape `$` character, otherwise it would match the end of line.

Comment: thanks mouviciel. But where did you mean escaping the $ char.

Comment: `$BUILD_NUMBER` is in the env object map, so it needs to be `env.BUILD_NUMBER`. Also, these are all being interpolated inside a string, so you probably need to enclose them like `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`, `${oldimageurl}`, etc. There will probably be a couple more problems after this, but this will get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the string variable in groovy, you don't need to add the double quotes. Also, you have an error in the interpolation. You'll do:

```
newimageurl = "***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xyz:v_${BUILD_NUMBER}"
oldimageurl = "***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xyz"
```

In you `sed` command as well (also, you have to put it inside an `sh` command):

```
sh """
sed -i -e 's#${oldimageurl}#${newimageurl}#' ./myfile.json
"""
```